# After install, LCD monitor is booted in unsupported frequency so I can't see the boot menu (GRUB)

Tags: boot, nvidia, menu, monitor

My graphic card is NVidia and monitor is LG 1280x1024

Answer (score 2):

Are you dual-booting or is this a single OS install, Because if this is a single OS install then the GRUB menu doesn't show unless you hold down the shift key after the computer posts. So if this is the case and you can get to the GRUB menu while holding shift then you can boot into recovery mode with safe graphics to help further troubleshoot the problem.